# View can't be associated with his controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view:

**View:**

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Axa Management System v1.0</legend>

@model InsuranceWebAPI.Models.User

@using (Html.BeginForm("getUserById", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <p>User id:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id);
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Get by id</button>

}


@using (Html.BeginForm("getUserByName", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{


    <p>User name:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name);
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Get by name</button>


}
```

Associated with this controller:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    private ActionResult getUserByName(string Name)
    {

        string receivedData;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
            .Create("http://afunnyurl.com");

          /*Awesome code*/

        return View("Index");
    }
```

But for some reason the view can't access to the method getUserByName() :(

I can access perfectly to the first method, getUserByID() and his controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getUserById(string Id)
    {
        string receivedData;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
            .Create("http://www.anawesomeutl.com");

        /*More awesome code*/


       return View("Index")
    }
```

I don't understand why I can't access to the second method (getUserByName()) :)

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Currently the visibility of this method is `private`. You need to change it to `public`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getUserByName(string Name)
{
   // to do  : Return something
}
```

private methods are accessible from withing the containing class/type.

Comment: Wow! I can't belive the mistake... Thanks @Shyju !